# Charts Render Double-counted Data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I'm trying to create a dashboard using data from 2 csv files. The csv are exactly the same except for two of the columns (score and total) contain different values. Because of dc.js limitations, I had to aggregate them. However, when rendering the charts, the counts were doubled (one for each csv). My csv looks similar to this:

"data1.csv"

```
agegroup    gender  group   scores  total
  18-24       M      1       0.04    1
  45-54       F      2       2.23    13
  25-34       M      1       0.74    6
  25-34       M      2       1.47    8
  18-24       F      1       2.88    7
  35-44       F      2       3.98    14
```

"data2.csv"

```
 agegroup   gender  group   scores  total
  45-54       F      1       4.93    8
  35-44       M      2       1.13    4
  18-24       M      1       5.28    9
  25-34       M      2       1.95    20
  18-24       F      1       0.52    18
```

Ideally what I would like is to still make a dashboard that could sum up the totals and scores depending on if I select `data1.csv` or `data2.csv`, but if I were to select both, it wouldn't sum up my `total` and `scores` column twice.

```
//using queue.js to load data
var q = queue()
  .defer(d3.csv, "data1.csv")
  .defer(d3.csv, "data2.csv");

  q.await(function(error, data1, data2){

  //initiatizing crossfilter and ingesting data
  var ndx = crossfilter();
  ndx.add(data1.map(function(d){
    return { age: d.age,
             gender: d.gender,
             scores: +d.scores,
             total: +d.total,
             type: 'data1'};
    }));

  ndx.add(data2.map(function(d){
    return { age: d.age,
             gender: d.gender,
             scores: +d.scores,
             total: +d.total,
             type: 'data2'};
    }));

//initializing charts
totalDisplay = dc.numberDisplay("#total-display");
totalScores = dc.numberDisplay("#total-scores");

//groupAll function to sum up the values. 
var scoresGroup = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {
          return d.scores;
        });
        var totalGroup = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) { 
          return d.total;
        });

//parameters for the number display. Currently it is returning NaN
totalDisplay
        .formatNumber(d3.format(","))
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .group(totalGroup);

totalScores
        .formatNumber(d3.format(",f"))
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
            return d;
        })
        .group(scoresGroup);
```

Comment: seems like kind of a strange way to deal with the problem, when it sounds like you really want to *join* the CSVs (by reading one of them and then adding the missing columns from the other).

Comment: I reread it and saw that it could be misconstrued. While the columns are the same the scores and total column contain different values. I've reworded it. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean you want the data entirely separate? If so, you should use two crossfilter instances and two chart groups. Otherwise I'm not sure why the counts would be doubled except if you are counting the same rows twice, i.e. you really want score1 and score2 in the same row.

Comment: @Gordon, I haven't thought of that. Quick question, under 2 instances, what if I want the counts of both csvs for males and females or a crosstabulation to see the counts broken down by gender between the two csvs?

Comment: It is sounding more and more like you really want to join the two tables, but it's hard to say without seeing your data. In any case, it really seems to be a question about how to combine your data, not really a question about the charts. Could you edit your question with an example of the data, or start a new question here or on the user group?

Comment: @Gordon, I added in an example csv for you to look through. Hopefully this provides a better picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81454/discussion-between-minh-mai-and-gordon).